# Multilanguge site in Orchard 1.4

Tags: orchardcms, multilingual

Can someone please point me to making multilanguage site in Orchard CMS 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

Sure: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-global-ready-applications

Comment: In addition to Bertrand's answer, I would suggest to take a look at the CulturePicker module. It adds some nice enhancements, that you might need. 
It's recently upgraded for Orchard v1.4 support.

Comment: Would be nice actually to add a note to the doc topic pointing to that module.